# My form does not send data to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I was following this tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/a-xml-web-service-that-update-data-into-a-default-table-of-t/

And now that I finished it, when I press send the data does not go into the DB, however the code does run in the web service page, just not the forms.

My web service code:

```
public class SampleService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        [WebMethod]
        public int insertPerson(string firstName, string lastName, string DOB, int phoneNumber, string address, int postCode)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=collegedatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName, DOB, phoneNumber, address, postCode) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @DOB, @phoneNumber, @address, @postCode)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", postCode);
            int roweffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            return roweffected;
        }
```

and my .aspx.cs code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string firstName = TextBox34.Text;
            string lastName = TextBox35.Text;
            string  DOB = TextBox36.Text;
            int phoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox38.Text);
            string address = TextBox37.Text;
            int postCode = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox39.Text);
            SampleService myservice = new SampleService();
            int temp = myservice.insertPerson(firstName, lastName, DOB, phoneNumber, address, postCode);
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                messageLabel.Text = "record is update";
            }
            else
            {
                messageLabel.Text = "record is not update";
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

So at some point I changed the button name and that's why it wasn't running, however upon changing the button name and clicking the button, I get a crash and the program points to the conn string in the web service, and says that `Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'.`

Comment: Did you come across any error?What's the result of temp after you run the "InsertPerson" method?

Comment: No, there are no errors or warnings

Comment: What's the result of "roweffected" after you run cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();?

Comment: does it run locally? replace `.` with your `hostname` in `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: What is the value of `rowseffected` once it has run?

Comment: I don't see the value of roweeffected, I might be doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Place your connection in a `using` block so that it closes and commits the transaction.

```
public int insertPerson(string firstName, string lastName, string DOB, int phoneNumber, string address, int postCode)
    {
       using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=collegedatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
       {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName, DOB,     phoneNumber, address, postCode) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @DOB, @phoneNumber, @address, @postCode)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", postCode);
        int roweffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        return roweffected;
        }
    }
```

OR

call

```
con.Close();
```

Comment: Tried this and the form still doesn't send the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `ProviderName` as second parameter while supplying `connection string`.

i suggest you to add both c`onnectionstring` and `providername` in web.config file and access them from code behind.

Add the following statements into the `web.config` file

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=collegedatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />
</connectionStrings>
```

to access the `connectionctring` from `web.config` file try this:

**Code behind:**

```
String connectionstring=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
```

**Complete Code:**

```
public class SampleService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        [WebMethod]
        public int insertPerson(string firstName, string lastName, string DOB, int phoneNumber, string address, int postCode)
        {
String connectionstring=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

            con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName, DOB, phoneNumber, address, postCode) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @DOB, @phoneNumber, @address, @postCode)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", postCode);
            int roweffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            return roweffected;
        }
```

Comment: This runs locally on Visual Studio, the Conn string is straight from the VS string it gives you, it works.

Comment: @user2469932: remove `Integrated Security=True` in connection string and then try

Comment: @user2469932: did you try by removing `Integrated Security=True` from your connection string?

Comment: @user2469932: check my edited answer it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the button name to match and also had to remove the`using block`

Comment: using block is much more recommended than your current code, i dont see any con.close() codes afterall